# Unable to show the response in alert or console

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm working on a website in which I need to make a GET request to a webservice and log the response. I'm trying the below code in jsp.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var a = this.responseText;
    alert(a);
    console.log(a);
}
    ...
xhttp.open("GET", "https://example.com/test.ashx", true);
xhttp.send();
```

I am able to see the response in Firefox networks tab. But alert/console log doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you get any error messages in your console?

Comment: No. The JSON response is shown in the browser, but looks like it is not sent to the server.

Comment: Its not a direct answer to your question,  but try the native fetch instead of doing yourself the ajax request, its much much easier. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        var a = this.responseText; 
        alert(a);
        console.log(a);
   }
}

xhttp.open("GET", "https://example.com/test.ashx", true);
xhttp.send();
```

Comment: Why? What have you changed? "try this" is not an answer

Comment: The line "if (xhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) " is added in this answer and which is not in original code